# How to change the value of a variable after several calculations

Tags: java, vector, normalize

The following Java code is used to normalize a vector with the variables dx and dy.

My Problem is that the second calculation is executed with the changed variable of dx which gives me a wrong value for dy.
How do i prevent this or change both values after the calculations?

Thanks in advance for any answer

```
    public void rescale() {
    dx = (1/(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2)))) * dx;

    dy = (1/(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2)))) * dy;
}
```

Comment: Save the initial values into a temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

Store `dx` in a temp variable so that you may keep original value.

```
 public void rescale() {
    double dxTmp = dx;
    dx = (1/(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2)))) * dx;

    dy = (1/(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dxTmp, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2)))) * dy;
}
```